# Remove a single non-unique value from a sequence in F#

Tags: f#

I have a sequence of integers representing dice in F#.

In the game in question, the player has a pool of dice and can choose to play one (governed by certain rules) and keep the rest.

If, for example, a player rolls a 6, 6 and a 4 and decides to play one the sixes, is there a simple way to return a sequence with only one 6 removed?

```
Seq.filter (fun x -> x != 6) dice
```

removes all of the sixes, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below code will work for a list (so not any seq but it sounds like the sequence your using could be a List)

```
let rec removeOne value list = 
               match list with
               | head::tail when head = value -> tail
               | head::tail -> head::(removeOne value tail)
               | _ -> [] //you might wanna fail here since it didn't find value in
                                   //the list
```

EDIT: code updated based on correct comment below. Thanks P

EDIT: After reading a different answer I thought that a warning would be in order. Don't use the above code for infite sequences but since I guess your players don't have infite dice that should not be a problem but for but for completeness here's an implementation that would work for (almost) any 
finite sequence

```
 let rec removeOne value seq acc = 
                   match seq.Any() with
                   | true when s.First() = value -> seq.Skip(1)
                   | true -> seq.First()::(removeOne value seq.Skip(1))
                   | _ -> List.rev acc //you might wanna fail here since it didn't find value in
                                       //the list
```

However I recommend using the first solution which Im confident will perform better than the latter even if you have to turn a sequence into a list first (at least for small sequences or large sequences with the soughtfor value in the end)

Comment: I don't understand the "to avoid concatenation ..." part, especially since there is an `@` in your function. Is `(List.rev a)@b` compiled into revappend by F#? Even so, that's still a concatenation, that you could avoid by simply storing the traversed values on the stack: `| heat::tail when head <> value -> head::(removeOne value tail)`

Comment: Also, using nested calls to `seq.Skip(1)` will lead to a very inefficient code (In fact, _O(n)_ access time, because each call to `Skip` creates one indirection). The patterns used when working with F# lists simply don't work for sequences.

Comment: @Tomas yes which exactly my point when stating that creating a list before hand might very Well perform better

Comment: You're quite right that the numbers are being stored as list initially: I was making my own life awkward trying to build an overly general function.

Had I really needed a way to deal with a more general case, I'm afraid I would have been going with Tomas'.

Answer (score 4):

Non-trivial operations on sequences are painful to work with, since they don't support pattern matching. I think the simplest solution is as follows:

```
let filterFirst f s =
    seq {
        let filtered = ref false
        for a in s do
            if filtered.Value = false && f a then
                filtered := true
            else yield a
    }
```

So long as the mutable implementation is hidden from the client, it's still functional style ;)

Comment: I like this answer, but I think using `not filtered.Value` would be preferable to comparing to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to store data I would use ResizeArray instead of a Sequence.  It has a wealth of functions built in such as the function you asked about.  It's simply called Remove. ***Note***: [ResizeArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx) is an abbreviation for the CLI type [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hw1as6.aspx).

```
let test = seq [1; 2; 6; 6; 1; 0]
let a = new ResizeArray<int>(test)
a.Remove 6 |> ignore
Seq.toList a |> printf "%A"

// output
> [1; 2; 6; 1; 0]
```

Other data type options could be Array

```
let removeOneFromArray v a =
    let i = Array.findIndex ((=)v) a
    Array.append a.[..(i-1)] a.[(i+1)..]
```

or List

```
let removeOneFromList v l = 
    let rec remove acc = function
        | x::xs when x = v -> List.rev acc @ xs
        | x::xs -> remove (x::acc) xs
        | [] -> acc
    remove [] l
```

Comment: I guess this goes against FP principles because a.Remove mutates the list

Comment: @knocte Sure, however there are cases where you want to encapsulate mutation inside of a function or object such that it is exposed in an immutable way.  A lot of the F# run-time functions use mutable data underneath.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any function that would allow you to directly represent the idea that you want to remove just the first element matching the specified criteria from the list (e.g. something like `Seq.removeOne`).

You can implement the function in a relatively readable way using `Seq.fold` (if the sequence of numbers is finite):

```
let removeOne f l = 
  Seq.fold (fun (removed, res) v ->
    if removed then true, v::res
    elif f v then true, res
    else false, v::res) (false, []) l 
  |> snd |> List.rev

> removeOne (fun x -> x = 6) [ 1; 2; 6; 6; 1 ];
val it : int list = [1; 2; 6; 1]
```

The `fold` function keeps some state - in this case of type `bool * list<'a>`. The Boolean flag represents whether we already removed some element and the list is used to accumulate the result (which has to be reversed at the end of processing).

If you need to do this for (possibly) infinite `seq<int>`, then you'll need to use `GetEnumerator` directly and implement the code as a recursive sequence expression. This is a bit uglier and it would look like this:

```
let removeOne f (s:seq<_>) = 
  // Get enumerator of the input sequence
  let en = s.GetEnumerator()

  let rec loop() = seq {
    // Move to the next element
    if en.MoveNext() then
      // Is this the element to skip?
      if f en.Current then
        // Yes - return all remaining elements without filtering
        while en.MoveNext() do
          yield en.Current
      else
        // No - return this element and continue looping
        yield en.Current
        yield! loop() }
  loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
let rec removeFirstOccurrence item screened items =

    items |> function
    | h::tail -> if h = item
                 then screened @ tail
                 else tail |> removeFirstOccurrence item (screened @ [h])
    | _ -> []
```

Usage:

```
let updated = products |> removeFirstOccurrence product []
```