# Remove elements during infinite sequence generation

Tags: haskell, data-structures, f#

I found a great haskell solution ([source](http://bonsaicode.wordpress.com/2013/02/01/programming-praxis-hofstadters-sequence/)) for generating a [Hofstadter sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence):

```
hofstadter = unfoldr (\(r:s:ss) -> Just (r, r+s:delete (r+s) ss)) [1..]
```

Now, I am trying to write such a solution in F#, too. Unfortunately (I am not really familar to F#) I had no success so far.

My problem is, that when I use a `sequence` in F#, it seems not to be possible to remove an element (like it is done in the haskell solution).
Other data structures like `arrays`, `list` or `set` which allow to remove elements are not generating an infinite sequence, but operate on certain elements, only.

**So my question:** Is it possible in F# to generate an infinite sequence, where elements are deleted?

Some stuff I tried so far:

Infinite sequence of numbers:

```
let infinite =
    Seq.unfold( fun state -> Some( state, state + 1) ) 1
```

Hofstadter sequence - not working, because there is no `del` keyword and there are more syntax errors

```
let hofstadter =
    Seq.unfold( fun (r :: s :: ss) -> Some( r, r+s, del (r+s) ss)) infinite
```

I thought about using `Seq.filter`, but found no solution, either.

Comment: To get the same perf profile in F# you'll have to write this completely different. `LazyList` will work, but comes with linear memory growth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pad's solution is nice but, likely due to the way `LazyList` is implemented, stack overflows somewhere between 3-4K numbers. For curiosity's sake I wrote a version built around a generator function (`unit -> 'a`) which is called repeatedly to get the next element (to work around the unwieldiness of `IEnumerable`). I was able to get the first 10K numbers (haven't tried beyond that).

```
let hofstadter() =

  let delete x f =
    let found = ref false
    let rec loop() =
      let y = f()
      if not !found && x = y
      then found := true; loop()
      else y
    loop

  let cons x f =
    let first = ref true
    fun () -> 
      if !first
      then first := false; x
      else f()

  let next =
    let i = ref 0
    fun () -> incr i; !i

  Seq.unfold (fun next -> 
    let r = next()
    let s = next()
    Some(r, (cons (r+s) (delete (r+s) next)))) next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - I accepted your solution, because it seems like the way you should go as a F# developer.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need more than a `delete` function on sequence. Your example requires pattern matching on inifinite collections, which sequence doesn't support.

The F# counterpart of Haskell list  is [LazyList](https://github.com/fsharp/powerpack/blob/master/src/FSharp.PowerPack/LazyList.fsi) from F# PowerPack. LazyList is also potentially infinite and it supports pattern matching, which helps you to implement `delete` easily.

Here is a faithful translation:

```ml
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.LazyList

let delete x xs =  
    let rec loop x xs = seq {        
        match xs with
        | Nil -> yield! xs
        | Cons(x', xs') when x = x' -> yield! xs'
        | Cons(x', xs') ->
            yield x' 
            yield! loop x xs'
        }
    ofSeq (loop x xs)

let hofstadter =
    1I |> unfold (fun state -> Some(state, state + 1I))
       |> unfold (function | (Cons(r, Cons(s, ss))) -> 
                                 Some(r, cons (r+s) (delete (r+s) ss)) 
                           | _ -> None)
       |> toSeq
```

There are a few interesting things here:

- Use [sequence expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) to implement `delete` to ensure that the function is tail-recursive. A non-tail-recursive version should be easy.
- Use `BigInteger`; if you don't need too many elements, using `int` and [`Seq.initInfinite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370429.aspx) is more efficient.
- Add a case returning `None` to ensure exhaustive pattern matching.
- At last I convert `LazyList` to sequence. It gives better interoperability with .NET collections.

Implementing `delete` on sequence is uglier. If you are curious, take a look at [Remove a single non-unique value from a sequence in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705972/remove-a-single-non-unique-value-from-a-sequence-in-f) for reference.

Comment: _"LazyList is also potentially infinite"_ It's important to note that, unlike `seq<_>`, it's not truly infinite. Each computed element remains accessible and therefore memory usage steadily increases as the list is traversed. `seq<_>`, on the other hand, is a forward-only cursor, which keeps memory use constant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Especially the reference to LazyList is very interesting (haven't heard of it before).

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you can use filter and a design that follows the haskell solution (but, as @pad says, you don't have pattern matching on sequences; so I used lisp-style destruction):

```
let infinite = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i+1)

let generator = fun ss -> let (r, st)  = (Seq.head ss, Seq.skip 1 ss)                               
                          let (s, stt) = (Seq.head st, Seq.skip 1 st)
                          let srps     = seq [ r + s ]
                          let filtered = Seq.filter (fun t -> (r + s) <> t) stt
                          Some (r, Seq.append srps filtered)

let hofstadter = Seq.unfold generator infinite                               

let t10 = Seq.take 10 hofstadter |> Seq.toList
// val t10 : int list = [1; 3; 7; 12; 18; 26; 35; 45; 56; 69]
```

I make no claims about efficiency though!

Comment: yes, I merely wanted to show that there was a solution directly matching Tanascius' formulation. It would be interesting to know just how much worse a naive implementation like this is than @pad's.

Comment: To get the first 1K numbers: pad's - `Real: 00:00:01.198, CPU: 00:00:01.248, GC gen0: 56, gen1: 28, gen2: 1`; yours - `Real: 00:00:53.166, CPU: 00:00:53.149, GC gen0: 1201, gen1: 6, gen2: 0`. Yours takes 44x as long and GC's 21x as much. Huge difference.

Comment: And, for the curious, my version for comparison: `Real: 00:00:00.081, CPU: 00:00:00.078, GC gen0: 2, gen1: 0, gen2: 0`.

Comment: @Daniel: Did you compare both using `bigint` or both using `int`?

Comment: Oops. I didn't notice yours uses `bigint`. However, I just changed it to `int` and re-ran. Didn't make much difference: `Real: 00:00:00.923, CPU: 00:00:00.920, GC gen0: 52, gen1: 25, gen2: 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I appreciate how similar it is to the haskell code.